# Powershell Script to get files from last year folder

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I have situation where I have 3000 vendors in folder structure. Each vendor then has folders for each year (2001, .... 2014) and other folders as well. Is there a way to list all the files that is in latest year (whichever year).

Basically, I need to upload all the latest agreement files from file-share to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

One Liner

```
Get-ChildItem | %{ $_.FullName | Get-ChildItem [1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | sort -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Get-ChildItem }
```

You start from the root folder, for each folder you get all the folders which name looks like a year, sort them, take the first one, and get all it's folders.

Of course, there is a plenty of issues with this. e.g. there has to be at least one year folder, no 'year' files etc. I will leave you tackle that kind of problems.

Comment: The script is not working because folder structure looks like Y:\Agreements\0 to C\0\0 Supplier\Agreement\ then bunch of year folder. 

Another example,

\Agreements\D to H\E\Edmund Power Contractor LLC\Agreement\ then bunch of year folder

It will be so much for me to drill down each vendor folder then agreement folder and run the shell command 3000 times.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recursively iterate through all the directories, matching the ones that are equivalent to the current year:

```
$thisYearDirs = get-childitem -Directory -Recurse | where {$_.Name -eq (get-date).year}
```

then you would just get the files in each of those:

```
$thisYearDirs | get-childitem
```

You could also do it all in one line:

```
get-childitem -Directory -Recurse | where {$_.Name -eq (get-date).year} | get-childitem
```

Note that the `-directory` switch needs powershell v3, you could filter out directories in earlier versions by modifying the where clause condition to do it:

```
get-childitem -Recurse | where {$_.PSIsCOntainer -and $_.Name -eq (get-date).year} | get-childitem
```